# Hyundai Elantra 2007 - Disable automatic volume leveling?

Tags: hyundai, elantra, audio

My fiancé has a 2007 Hyundai Elantra that does this crazy volume adjustment when driving.

It seems like it's trying to compensate for road/engine noise, but it's just doing it all wrong. It gets quieter when things get louder, and louder when things get quieter. It's complete nonsense.

Is there any way to just disable it outright? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hyundai appears to call this feature SDVC (Speed Dependent Volume Control). Check your owners manual for how to turn this off.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking a problem involving one or other of the following. Radio has a setting to set the auto  volume control which needs a reset. The vehicles antenna is faulty or suffering poor continuity in its wiring. The radio set itself has developed a fault. The way forward is for a hands on check from your favourite auto electrician.

Comment: "The way forward is for a hands on check from your favourite auto electrician." - I disagree with this. Something as simple as checking radio settings is very much a DIY task. Your list of possible issues looks correct though.